# How to connect to production machine using SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

How do I connect to a production machine using SSH tunnel? It has few blocked ports which I would like to connect from my development box and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
ssh -N -v -L<LOCAL_PORT>:<PRODUCTION_MACHINE>:<PRODUCTION_PORT> <PRODUCTION_MACHINE>
```

E.g) ssh -N -v -L2047:my-production-server.com:8000 my-production-server.com